# [TypeError]: Firebase orderByChild not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to query my database such that it retrieves an ordered list based on each child key. I do it as follows (see below), but "TypeError" happens. That is ordered at random when using `.on('value', snapshot =>`. I can't fix that, do you guys have any ideas to realize?

#### The Error

> TypeError: In this environment the sources for assign MUST be an object. This error is a performance optimization and not spec compliant.

#### Realtime Database Query

[image: RealtimeDatabase Query]

#### Source Code

```html
export const messagesFetch = (room) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.database().ref(`/rooms/${room.roomId}/messages`)
    .once('child_added', snapshot => {
      dispatch({ type: 'messages_fetch_success', payload: snapshot.val() });
    })
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`child_added` will create a new snapshot for each message, instead of returning a list of messages in one object.

You might want to look at `.once('value')` instead of `once('child_added')`.

As you wanted an ordered list I added the query `orderByKey()` which will return the messages in key order.

```
export const messagesFetch = (room) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.database().ref(`/rooms/${room.roomId}/messages`)
      .orderByKey()
      .once('value')
      .then(snapshots => {
        snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
          dispatch({ type: 'messages_fetch_success', payload: snapshot.val() });

          return false;
        });        
      });
  };
};
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but that would not work. Same error occurs after code editing.

Answer (score 0):

Is a react-native app, right?! If yes add a flag in question.

In firebase 'child_added' fires for each child and ever a new child has add, like **sketchthat** says. With 'once' you not listen the node, but, because 'child_added' you fires your function for every child. In other words your function return differents values (snapshot) for a same constant.